# $\|x\| \leq \|x(h)\|$ for all $x\in A$ implies $\dim A < \infty$.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $A\subseteq B(H)$ be a unital inclusion of $C^*$-algebras. Suppose that there is a vector $h \in H$ such that $\|x \| \leq \|x(h)\|$ for all $x \in A$. Does it follow that $A$ is finite-dimensional?

Attempt/observations:

Not really sure how to start. Somehow we want to show that a set of linearly independent vectors in $A$ must be finite.

- Taking $x=1$, we see that $\|h\| \geq 1$.
- Maybe we can show that if $A$ has infinite dimension, then there is $x \in A$ with $\|x\|> \|x(h)\|$, or equivalently $\|x^*x\| > \langle x^*xh,h\rangle.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The condition forces $A$ to be  finite-dimensional.

This is because the inequality will also hold for the double commutant $A''$. Indeed, $A''$ is the sot-closure of $A$. If $x=\lim_{sot}x_j$ and $\|x_j\|\leq\|x_jh\|$, then
$$
\|x\|\leq\limsup_j\|x_j\|\leq\limsup_j\|x_jh\|=\|xh\|. 
$$
Being a von Neumann algebra, $A''$ is the norm closure of the span of its projections. Let $p_1,\ldots,p_m\in A''$ be pairwise orthogonal projections. Then
$$
\|h\|^2=\sum_j\|p_kh\|^2\geq m
$$
So $A''$ admits only finitely many pairwise orthogonal projections. This forces $A''$ (and, a fortiori, $A$, since they are now equal) to be finite-dimensional.

Comment: Why is the last sentence true? Note that a von Neumann algebra is not the closed span of its pairwise orthogonal projections (unless the von Neumann algebra is commutative).

Comment: I never said that. $$\ $$ Any type I$_\infty$, II, or III component has families of infinitely many pairwise orthogonal projections.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid factor theory?

Comment: The type decomposition has nothing to do with factors. In any case, I don't see a way to address this without somehow resorting to factors; a finite-dimensional von Neumann algebra is nothing by a finite direct sum of finite-dimensional factors.